# ¿Hay alguna forma de optimizar este código php?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, optimización

Para resumir, quise hacer una alta a una base de datos por medio de código PHP. La lógica del mismo se basa por medio de condicionales *if* y trata de lo siguiente: en mi index.html tengo varios inputs, algunos obligatorios y otros opcionales; en esos *if* lo que estoy haciendo es validar, primero, si los campos opcionales tienen algún valor, si es *true* que haga una alta a la base de datos con la información que encuentre en todos los inputs. En cambio, si encuentra un valor en un solo input opcional, que haga el *query* agregando lo que encuentre en los inputs obligatorios y en **1** solo input opcional (el único que tiene algo). Quisiera encontrar alguna forma de optimizar este código para una mejor lectura y una mas rápida ejecución. ¡Muchas gracias!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pink-store-db") or die ("Problemas de conexión"); 
        
        if ($_REQUEST["nombre2"] != "" && $_REQUEST["apellido2"] != "") {
            ("Error en la conexión");
            mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usu_nombre1, usu_nombre2, usu_apellido1, usu_apellido2, usu_email, cel) 
            VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre1]', '$_REQUEST[nombre2]', '$_REQUEST[apellido1]', '$_REQUEST[apellido2]', '$_REQUEST[email]', '$_REQUEST[cel]')")
            or die ("Problemas en el query: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
        } else if ($_REQUEST["nombre2"] != "") {
            mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usu_nombre1, usu_nombre2, usu_apellido1, usu_email, cel) 
            VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre1]', '$_REQUEST[nombre2]','$_REQUEST[apellido1]', '$_REQUEST[email]', '$_REQUEST[cel]')")
            or die ("Problemas en el query: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
        } else {
            mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usu_nombre1, usu_nombre2, usu_apellido1, usu_email, cel) 
            VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre1]', '$_REQUEST[apellido1]', '$_REQUEST[apellido2]','$_REQUEST[email]', '$_REQUEST[cel]')")
            or die ("Problemas en el query: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
        }
            
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<form action="PHP/register.php" method="post">
            <h2>
                ¿QUIÉN ERES?
            </h2>
            <div class="inputs-text">
                <input type="text" placeholder="PRIMER NOMBRE" name="nombre1" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="SEGUNDO NOMBRE" name="nombre2">
                <input type="text" placeholder="PRIMER APELLIDO" name="apellido1" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="SEGUNDO APELLIDO" name="apellido2">
                <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="E-MAIL" name="email" required>
                <input type="number" class="cel" placeholder="NÚMERO DE TELÉFONO" name="cel" required>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Si los valores aue no especificas quedan en la base de datos almacenados como null, lo que puedes hacer es una sola consulta especificando todos los valores todos los valores de las columnas, y en los valores el valor especificado o null si no se específicó

Comment: La verdad no te entiendo jaja.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te dijeron, puedes especificar los campos vacíos como `NULL`.

No será el código más elegante, pero lo siguiente elimina la necesidad de usar los `if`. Si un campo que no es obligatorio viene vacío, se escribirá `NULL` en esa columna de la tabla.

```php
$nombre1 = "'$_POST[nombre1]'";
$nombre2 = empty($_POST['nombre2']) ? "NULL" : "'$_POST[nombre2]'";
$apellido1 = "'$_POST[apellido1]'";
$apellido2 = empty($_POST['apellido2']) ? "NULL" : "'$_POST[apellido2]'";
$email = "'$_POST[email]'";
$cel = "'$_POST[cel]'";

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios 
    (usu_nombre1, usu_nombre2, usu_apellido1, usu_apellido2, usu_email, cel) 
    VALUES ($nombre1, $nombre2, $apellido1, $apellido2, $email, $cel)";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

---

Si los nombres de los campos en el formulario HTML fuesen iguales a las columnas de la tabla en la base de datos, sería bastante sencillo. ¡Advertencia! Usa [Arrow functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) - PHP 7.4 o superior.

```php
$data = array_filter($_POST); // <-- array_filter elimina los valores vacíos
$col_names = implode(', ', array_keys($data));
$col_values = implode(', ', array_map(fn($val)=>"'$val'", array_values($data)));
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios ($col_names) VALUES ($col_values)";
mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
```

Considera usar Sentencias Preparadas o PDO, por las [inyecciones SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/80870).

Comment: +1 porque es el único que le dice que concatenar las variables directamente es inseguro.

Answer (score 1):

Tal como te expliqué en el comentario lo que yo haría sería declarar todos los campos y los que sean opcionales si no tienen valor enviarlos `null`.

Veo que los unicos campos opcionales son `nombre2` y `apellido2`, entonces sería algo asi:

```
//A los opcionales les asignas NULL si no tienen valor o tienen un valor vacio
$_REQUEST["nombre2"] = !empty($_REQUEST["nombre2"]) ? "'{$_REQUEST["nombre2"]}'" : "NULL";
$_REQUEST["apellido2"] = !empty($_REQUEST["apellido2"]) ? "'{$_REQUEST["apellido2"]}'" : "NULL";
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usu_nombre1, usu_nombre2, usu_apellido1, usu_apellido2, usu_email, cel) 
            VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre1]', $_REQUEST[nombre2], '$_REQUEST[apellido1]', $_REQUEST[apellido2], '$_REQUEST[email]', '$_REQUEST[cel]')")
            or die ("Problemas en el query: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
```

Y como también te dijeron anteriormente, no es buena practica concatenar parametros que envia el usuario para crear las sentencias SQL, usa prepared statments y siempre sanitiza los datos de entrada.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo en el código que muestras, hay cuatro campos de la tabla para los cuales siempre se insertará valores: `usu_nombre1`, `usu_apellido1`, `usu_email` y `cel` (que supongo debió ser `usu_cel`).

Partiendo de esto, se me ocurre una forma de armar la *query*, empezando por dos arreglos que contengan, el primero; los nombres de los campos, y el segundo; sus respectivos valores. Luego, solo haría falta verificar que tanto la variable `$_POST['usu_nombre2']` como `$_POST['usu_apellido2']` sean diferentes a una cadena vacía o, lo que es lo mismo, que su contenido (el valor) posea una extensión, para lo cual podemos recurrir a la función [strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php). Dado que ambas variables no son dependientes una de la otra, es decir, que no es necesario que ambas tengan o no tengan valores para ser insertadas o ignoradas **a la vez**, será necesario utilizar dos condiciones para evaluar la extensión de sus valores. En cada caso, si se comprueba que su valor posee una extensión (uno o más caracteres), se insertarán los datos que correspondan a los arreglos de los campos y valores.

Finalmente, se une todo en una sola cadena de consulta y quedará lista para ser utilizada. Para este ejemplo, me apoyaré de la función [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php) para poder trabajar directamente con los índices de las variables que llegan en el global `$_POST`.

```
extract($_POST);
$fields = ['usu_nombre1', 'usu_apellido1', 'usu_email', 'cel'];
$values = ["'$usu_nombre1'", "'$usu_apellido1'", "'$usu_email'", "'$cel'"];

if (strlen($usu_nombre2)){
    $fields[] = 'usu_nombre2';
    $values[] = "'$usu_nombre2'";
}

if (strlen($usu_apellido2)){
    $fields[] = 'usu_apellido2';
    $values[] = "'$usu_apellido2'";
}

$fields = implode(', ', $fields);
$values = implode(', ', $values);
$query = "INSERT INTO usuarios ($fields) VALUES ($values)";

mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or exit(mysqli_error($conexion));
```

He colocado en cada condición a la variable pasada como argumento de la función `strlen()`, pero no hago la comparación `strlen(variable) > 0` porque, al dejarla así, como está, automáticamente se evaluará el valor como si se tratara de un *booleano*, por lo que, cuando la extensión del valor de la variable sea igual a cero, se evaluará como `false` y no se cumplirá la condición. Cualquier número superior a cero (no puede haber una extensión negativa) siempre será `true`.

Asimismo, para concatenar los valores de los arreglos con la consulta, previamente genero cadenas a partir de dichos valores utilizando la función [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php), misma que une los elementos de un arreglo y devuelve una cadena de ellos.

Un ejemplo de cómo resultaría una cadena de consulta sin el segundo nombre pero con el segundo apellido:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios (usu_nombre1, usu_apellido1, usu_apellido2, usu_email, cel) VALUES ('Horacio', 'Vargas', 'Zapata', 'horaciovz@outlook.com', '999999999')
```

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te dice Pipe es que hagas un solo query para el Insert, colocando todas las columnas y valores en el mismo string.

Que es basicamente el primer Insert que haces:

```
mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO usuarios (usu_nombre1, usu_nombre2, usu_apellido1, usu_apellido2, usu_email, cel) 
            VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre1]', '$_REQUEST[nombre2]', '$_REQUEST[apellido1]', '$_REQUEST[apellido2]', '$_REQUEST[email]', '$_REQUEST[cel]')")
```

El problema es que no estarías guardan `null` para los casos vacios, si no que guardarías un string que dice `'null'`, para esto puede crear una función, que le llamaré `GetValor`

```
function GetValor($nombre){
     if(!isset($_REQUEST[$nombre]) || $_REQUEST[$nombre]=="") return null;
     return "'".$_REQUEST[$nombre]."'";
}
```

Luego, si los `name` de los inputs los haces cohincidir con los nombres de las columnas en la base de datos tambien te ahorras unos pasos. Algo así:

```
 function GetValor($nombre){
     if(!isset($_REQUEST[$nombre]) || $_REQUEST[$nombre]=="") return null;
     return "'".$_REQUEST[$nombre]."'";
 }
 
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pink-store-db") or die 
 ("Problemas de conexión"); 

 $columnas = ["usu_nombre1", "usu_nombre2", "usu_apellido1", "usu_apellido2", "usu_email", "cel"];
 $valores = array_map("GetValor",$columnas);
 $query = "INSERT INTO usuarios (". implode(',',$columnas).") VALUES(".implode(',',$valores).")";

 mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die ("Problemas en el query: " . mysqli_error($conexion));
```

```
<form action="PHP/register.php" method="post">

    <h2>
        ¿QUIÉN ERES?
    </h2>
    <div class="inputs-text">
        <input type="text" placeholder="PRIMER NOMBRE" name="usu_nombre1" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="SEGUNDO NOMBRE" name="usu_nombre2" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="PRIMER APELLIDO" name="usu_apellido1" required />
        <input type="text" placeholder="SEGUNDO APELLIDO" name="usu_apellido2" />
        <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="E-MAIL" name="usu_email" required />
        <input type="number" class="cel" placeholder="NÚMERO DE TELÉFONO" name="cel" required />
    </div>
</form>
```

*Notar que en el form los nombres son los mismo nombres de las columnas*